# Why does PlotRange in DensityPlot have no effect

Tags: plotting

It looks like `DensityPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` automatically clip the plot range to the min and max value of the data, when `PlotRange` is set to be larger.

For example:

When the plot range is smaller than the range of the data PlotRange works

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

but when the plot range is larger than the range of the data, it has no effects

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-2, 2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

`PlotRange` in 3D and 1D behaves more like what we expected:

```
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

So why does `PlotRange` in `DensityPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` behave like this? It looks inconsistent to me.

Comment: I believe it is always automatically adapting the full color scale to the full function range. The first case SEEMS  to work but what you're really modifying is the function range that the colorfunction can "see"

Comment: @belisarius OK that makes sense. Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others mentioned, this is really an effect of `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-k, k}}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-k, k}}], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {-k, k}]] &), 
  PlotPoints -> 30], {k, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how the density plot should react to a `PlotRange` wider than the $z$ data range.

I think that the clipping you might be referring to happens in two other places:

1. The `ColorFunctionScaling` is True by default, so in this case `ColorFunction` is passed $z$ scaled to lie in the $(0,1)$ interval. The values considered for the rescaling are those function values that lie within the `PlotRange`. If your manual `PlotRange` clips the function, then this setting has an effect, but if your manual `PlotRange`includes all function values, then the function's values themselves determine the scaling, and `PlotRange` becomes irrelevant.
2. The automatically generated `BarLegend` is also given the $(z_{min},\ z_{max})$ values to work with. You can change that by hand (e.g. `PlotLegends->BarLegend[{Automatic, {-10, 20}}]`) , but it won't influence the coloring in the plot.