# How to fix the PlotRange?

Tags: plotting

I have the following plot:

```
dat = {{255, 255, 255}, {0, 0, 153}, {0, 0, 0}, {204, 0, 0}, {255, 255, 255}};
With[{rgb = RGBColor @@@ (dat/255)}, cf = Blend[rgb, #] &;]
DensityPlot[E^(-2 p0^2 - x0^2/2)/π, {x0, -10, 10}, {p0, -7, 7}, 
ColorFunction -> cf, PlotLegends -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 1000, 
PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {-1, 1}}]
```

I try to fix the Plot Range from -1 to 1, but they only allow me to fix it between the maximum and the minimum value of the function, the problem is that i want to compare different plots from different calculations, I am interested just to fix the plotrange to a given one, independently of the function in the plot.
I thought it would be simple, but i cannot manage to do it.

Comment: the option of rescale is not posible, for what i comment about the later comparison with other results.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Try and take a look at the discussion in question [(82947)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/why-does-plotrange-in-densityplot-have-no-effect).

Comment: Specifically, try adding `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to establish the range of the PlotLegends bar to a given interval, we can add the following option to the DensityPlot

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}], Right]
```

[image]

Additionaly, we can adjust the x and y axes in the PlotRange option to produce a better result.