# Plot Range not working on list density plot and list contour plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of data `(x,y,f(x,y))` that I want to plot through a ListDensityPlot, and a ListContourPlot. When I specify the plot range using PlotRange the `x` and `y` range is correctly set, but the range for `f(x,y)` is selected automatically, i.e. the one I am selecting is ignored.

Here's the code I am using:

```
ListContourPlot[data /. t -> 1000*2 Pi, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[All, Below], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

You can clearly see that the range used is not the one I am specifying.

This might be a very stupid mistake on my side, but i am quite stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post your data so we can help you...

Comment: I actually found out that the problem i was getting is related to: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/why-does-plotrange-in-densityplot-have-no-effect?rq=1