# Parametrized density plots with a unified BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

I am plotting a function using `DensityPlot` for two different values of a parameter. I am setting the `PlotLegends` option to `Automatic`. The output I get gives me two density plots; one of whose ranges goes from `0.05` to `0.20` and the second one ranges from `-0.25` to `0.75`.

However, in the final output I want a `DensityPlot` whose range goes from `-0.5` to `1` so that the color for both plots is synchronized. I would really appreciate if someone could let me know how to do this. Here is the code I am using.

```
Clear[f, g, h, p, r, l, jac, u1, u2, u3, u4, G, x, y, z, sol, xinit, yinit, zinit, plotfunc0, plotfunc1, A, r1, r2]
r = 0.1;    
r2 = 0.9;
G = {{15, 15, 15, 6}, {10, 10, 10, 1}, {10, 10, 10, 1}, {16, 16, 16, 
   7}};     

u1[A_, De_] = 
 G[[1, 1]]*(1 - A)*(1 - De) +  G[[1, 2]]*(1 - A)*De + 
  G[[1, 3]]*A*(1 - De) +  G[[1, 4]]*A*De ;
u2[A_, De_] = 
  G[[2, 1]]*(1 - A)*(1 - De) +  G[[2, 2]]*(1 - A)*De + 
   G[[2, 3]]*A*(1 - De) +  G[[2, 4]]*A*De ;
u3[A_, De_] = 
  G[[3, 1]]*(1 - A)*(1 - De) +  G[[3, 2]]*(1 - A)*De + 
   G[[3, 3]]*A*(1 - De) +  G[[3, 4]]*A*De ;
u4[A_, De_] = 
  G[[4, 1]]*(1 - A)*(1 - De) +  G[[4, 2]]*(1 - A)*De + 
   G[[4, 3]]*A*(1 - De) +  G[[4, 4]]*A*De  ;
ualpha[A_, 
   De_] = ((1 - A)*(1 - De)*u1[A, De]) + ((1 - A)*De*
     u2[A, De]) + (A*(1 - De)*u3[A, De]) + (A*De*u4[A, De]);
us[A_, De_] = ((1 - A)*(1 - De)*u1[A, De]) + ((1 - A)*De *u2[A, De]);
ua[A_, De_] = (A*(1 - De)*u3[A, De]) + (A*De*u4[A, De]);
uc[A_, De_] = ((1 - A)*(1 - De)*u1[A, De]) + (A*(1 - De)*u3[A, De]);
ud[A_, De_] = ((1 - A)*De *u2[A, De]) + (A*De *u4[A, De]);
F1[A_, De_] = ((1 - r)*(1 - A)*(1 - De)*u1[A, De]/ualpha[A, De]) + (r*
     us[A, De]*uc[A, De]/((ualpha[A, De])^2)) - ((1 - A)*(1 - De));
F2[A_, De_] = ((1 - r)*(1 - A)*De*u2[A, De]/ualpha[A, De]) + (r*
     us[A, De]*ud[A, De]/((ualpha[A, De])^2)) - ((1 - A)*De);
F3[A_, De_] = ((1 - r)*A*(1 - De)*u3[A, De]/ualpha[A, De]) + (r*
     ua[A, De]*uc[A, De]/((ualpha[A, De])^2)) - (A*(1 - De));
scG[A_, De_] = F1[A, De]/((1 - A)*(1 - De));
adG[A_, De_] = ( -F1[A, De] - F2[A, De] - F3[A, De])/(A*De);
netG[A_, De_] = -scG[A, De] + adG[A, De];
G1[A_, De_] = ((1 - r2)*(1 - A)*(1 - De)*
     u1[A, De]/ualpha[A, De]) + (r2*us[A, De]*
     uc[A, De]/((ualpha[A, De])^2)) - ((1 - A)*(1 - De));
G2[A_, De_] = ((1 - r2)*(1 - A)*De*u2[A, De]/ualpha[A, De]) + (r2*
     us[A, De]*ud[A, De]/((ualpha[A, De])^2)) - ((1 - A)*De);
G3[A_, De_] = ((1 - r2)*A*(1 - De)*u3[A, De]/ualpha[A, De]) + (r2*
     ua[A, De]*uc[A, De]/((ualpha[A, De])^2)) - (A*(1 - De));
scG2[A_, De_] = G1[A, De]/((1 - A)*(1 - De));
adG2[A_, De_] = ( -G1[A, De] - G2[A, De] - G3[A, De])/(A*De);
netG2[A_, De_] = -scG2[A, De] + adG2[A, De];
DensityPlot[netG[A, DE], {A, 0, 1}, {DE, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14]]
DensityPlot[netG2[A, DE], {A, 0, 1}, {DE, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14]]
```

[image: Density plot 1]

[image: Density plot 2]

Comment: Also related: [82947](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82947/36508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g1 = DensityPlot[netG[A, DE], {A, 0, 1}, {DE, 0, 1}
   , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"][
       Rescale[#, {-0.5, 1.0}]] &)
   , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   , FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14]
   ];

g2 = DensityPlot[netG2[A, DE], {A, 0, 1}, {DE, 0, 1}
   , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"][
       Rescale[#, {-0.5, 1.0}]] &)
   , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   , FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14]
   ];

legend = BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-0.5, 1}}
   , LegendLayout -> "Column"
   , LegendMarkerSize -> 246];

Labeled[
 GraphicsRow[{g1, g2, legend}]
 , Grid[{{"NetG", "NetG2", "Range"}}
  , ItemSize -> {{19, 19, 4}, 1}
  , Alignment -> Center
  , Frame -> None
  ] (*end of Grid*)
 , Top
 ]
```

[image]